# package 'manifest designer package' failed to load Windows Phone SDK 8.0

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am very new to Windows Phone Development therefore I do not know much about it....

I installed Visual Studio 2012 in my Windows 8.1 64x Operating system after installation I downloaded Windows phone sdk 8.0 iso and installed it too ...

I watch tutorial and performs those steps , one of those tutorial's steps to double click WMAppManifiest.xml to change the icon of Windows Phone Apps  but When I double Click On this it gives following error

**package 'manifest designer package' failed to load**

and Also **AppManifest.xml**  is not loading and it gives this error

**Visual Studio has encounterd an unexpected error**

i have uninstalled all and re-install al of this including sdk and vs2012 but still it gives error not in one project but each time I tried to goto NewProject and select windows phone App  and without doing anything I tried to open those files but it gives error

Please Help me ....

Comment: Try updating your VS2014 to Update 4, then reinstalling the SDK.

Comment: Also, since you're on Windows 8.1 you can install VS2013 instead of VS2012. It sounds like your VS install is corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I was working on a Apache Cordova app in VS 2013. Try this it might help

I had a similar problem, but in my case it was to remove the text on the tile as it was too long for the tile. Each time I made a change to the platforms/wp8/Properties/WMAppManifest.xml it was overwritten each time when I Rebuilt the app.

I followed the below guide:

*Place the custom WMAppManifest.xml file in the res/native/wp8/Properties folder. Use the generated version of the file in the platforms/wp8/Properties folder after building a Debug configuration of the project for Windows Phone 8.*

Refer to this documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757053.aspx.